# Getting an iPhone app communicating with an Adobe Air desktop app

Tags: iphone, apache-flex, flash, networking, synchronization

I am creating a desktop version of an iPhone app and would like to have some sort of sync option.  The desktop version of the app is an Air app.

I know that I can have them communicate by:

1. Starting a server on the desktop or the phone
2. Ask the user to enter the IP of the device into the other one
3. Make GET and POST requests over the http server

This seems very clunky to me, however, and I would like for them to automatically recognize each others presence when the sync button is pressed.  How can this be done between an iPhone and an Air app?

Comment: To get them to connect sans user IP input your best bet might be a bonjour service. I do not know of any library for Bonjour + Air, sorry not much help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a way myself: Bonjour

It is possible to implement on the [Air side](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9780768680645/313#X2ludGVybmFsX0ZsYXNoUmVhZGVyP3htbGlkPTk3ODA3Njg2ODA2NDUvMzE0JmltYWdlcGFnZT0zMTQ=)
It is possible to implement on the [iPhone side](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameKit_Guide.pdf):